# error in c# DataAccess()

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to create a web application for e-learning system, as my mini-project. I got the code from a friend of mine. when I try to run my code I get error as "Data Access() namespace not found". do have any idea about how to debug that?

Comment: please post your code.

Comment: Please post your code up to your tired

Comment: It might be error in DLL file or database error. It better capturing your error and post here. Also Copy and paste the codes where you get errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might missed DLL file related to this name space or you missed project/dll in your solution.

So to avoid error add DLL or project which contains this namespace.

By the name is look like dataaccess related to your datalayer.